# Prevent expansion of table column when contents imcrease in size, fixed width

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image: screenshot]

as you can see, they arranged in a table layout, i set their layout weight to 1 and their weight sum to 4, at first they are all equal in width, but that changes when the nunber has a lot of digits, what to do?

i thought using a table layout was more convenient than multiple linear layouts haha

layout:

```
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Food"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Supplies"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Transport"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Misc"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTotalExpenses"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFoodExpense"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSuppliesExpense"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTransportExpense"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMiscExpense"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Please upload that layout file also

Comment: added layout code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mentioning `layout weight` but it will not work properly unless you set the width to `0dp` so set `layout_width` to `0dp` like this

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Food"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Supplies"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Transport"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Misc"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTotalExpenses"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFoodExpense"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSuppliesExpense"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTransportExpense"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="50000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMiscExpense"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```